# Returning Function Calls from an Array within a JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, algorithm, object-oriented

I'd like to use JavaScript to generate HTML.

I've made a JavaScript function object that has two parameters; a string and generic object. The string is used to specify the type of HTML element you want to generate and the generic object is a container for key value pairs specifying the element's attributes -- or a string for simple elements like paragraphs containing only text that needs no id or class specification.

I'm drafted some functions that generate some HTML elements. I then contained the functions in an array that is a local variable of a function called `html`.

When `html` is called with appropriate arguments (e.g. `html("element", {id:"myElement"})`), a string of HTML text is returned.

I wonder what the drawbacks of the approach are. More specifically, is there a better method to achieve the same results?

```
var html = function (type, spec={}) {
  html_element = [];

  html_element["table"] = function() {
    markup = "<table>";

    if (spec.cols) 
    {
      markup += "<tr>";

      for (value in spec.cols)
        markup += "<th>" + spec.cols[value] + "</th>";

      markup += "</tr>";
    }

    while (spec.rows.length)
    {
      markup += "<tr>";

      for (data in (row = spec.rows.shift()))
        markup += "<td>" + row[data] + "</td>";

      markup += "</tr>";
    }

    return markup += "</table>";
  };


  html_element["button"] = function() {
    if (spec.hasOwnProperty("value")) value = spec.value;
    else                              value = "";

    return "<button id=\"" + id + "\">" + value + "</button>";
  };


  html_element["p"] = function() {
    if (typeof spec === Object) text = spec.text;
    else                        text = spec;

    return "<p id=\"" + id + "\">" + text + "</p>";
  };

  ...


  return html_element[type]();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, is a good practice create sub functions instead of add all on an array.

```
var button = function() {

};
```

Always use `var` in front of the variables to scope to the context. ([good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398766/when-to-use-var-in-javascript)).

A good choice is take advantage of the evaluation of data types on javascript, for variables.

```
var variable = paramValue || "defaultValue";
```

this evaluates paramaValue, if is true, is assigned, if not, assign `"defaultValue"`

Also, if is possible, considere use a template engine like:

- http://handlebarsjs.com
- http://mustache.github.io

[Final Code](http://jsfiddle.net/4rcua2f7/1/)